# VIM caught deadly signal SEGV when opening PHP file

Tags: php, linux, vim, centos, segmentation-fault

I have PHP file on my virtual Linux CentOS machine and intermittently when I open it I am getting right away

> Vim: Caught deadly signal SEGV
>
> Vim: Finished. Segmentation fault.

I tested that file many times there are no any kind of hidden special characters. More over if I open another PHP file or for that matter any file and open my troubled file from it (`:e` file_name) I can view it, edit and save without any problems.

Any suggestions what is wrong with that file and how to fix it?

Comment: The way to fix it is to report the problem to vim_dev.

Answer (score 1):

Try following command:

```
vim -u NONE <your_file>
```

it will launch vim without processing `/etc/vimrc` and `~/.vimrc`

If you'll be able to edit your file then it means that the problem is one of your vim plugins. Try disabling them one by one and see what happens.

Comment: thank you. I tried it already and I know I can edit my file without any problems when VIM PHP plugin is disabled. However this problem is for just one particular file. All other PHP files I can edit with my plugin, not problems at all

Comment: So it means that the problem is not caused by `vim`. You should contact with developers of this particular plugin then.